# How can I compose two lists into one list (list of lists) by using for loop? The result has NULL value

Tags: r, for-loop, null

I am trying the merge hundreds lists to one.Not intend to modify the contents of lists, I just want to sequentially combine the lists. The names of lists has some rules, so I want to use for-loop with get() and paste0() function. But The for-loop only showed me NULL value. Here is the simple example which reflect my case.

These are the lists what I want to merge.

```
list_a <- list(1, 2, 3, 4)
list_b <- list('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
```

When I use list function directly, I can sucessfully get what I wanted

```
> list(list_a, list_b)
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] 1

[[1]][[2]]
[1] 2

[[1]][[3]]
[1] 3

[[1]][[4]]
[1] 4


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] "a"

[[2]][[2]]
[1] "b"

[[2]][[3]]
[1] "c"

[[2]][[4]]
[1] "d"
```

However, when I use for loop, I just could draw NULL value like below

```
naming <- c("list_a", "list_b")

aa <- list()
result <- for(i in 1:length(naming)){
aa[[i]] <- get(naming[i])  
}

> result
NULL
```

However, mysteriously, when I just dissolved the for-loop, I could get the right answer.

```
> list(get(naming[1]), get(naming[2]))
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] 1

[[1]][[2]]
[1] 2

[[1]][[3]]
[1] 3

[[1]][[4]]
[1] 4


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] "a"

[[2]][[2]]
[1] "b"

[[2]][[3]]
[1] "c"

[[2]][[4]]
[1] "d"
```

I don't know the reason why my for-loop not working. I attempted the designate the global enviorment in the function but it was not working too, only show NULL result.

Please give me some ideas to fix it.

Comment: Did you check `aa`?

Comment: Using `get()` and/or `for()` is really not the right solution here.

Comment: use `mget(naming)`

Comment: I confused basic of variable. I'll check the mget function. Thank you-!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the problem is in your syntax, since you are setting the `result` variable equal to a loop. This code works for me:

```
result <- list()
for(i in 1:length(naming)) {
    result[[i]] <- get(naming[i])
}

result
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] 1

[[1]][[2]]
[1] 2

[[1]][[3]]
[1] 3

[[1]][[4]]
[1] 4


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] "a"

[[2]][[2]]
[1] "b"

[[2]][[3]]
[1] "c"

[[2]][[4]]
[1] "d"
```

Comment: Thank you. My knowledge of R is not solid yet. I have confused. Actually, there was no need to designate the variable when run for-loop. Thank you for your advice.

Comment: You're welcome! And no worries, although R is not all simple, I'm sure you'll get there. :) Best of luck!

Comment: We try to avoid writing `1L:length(x)` inside `for()`; the use of `seq_len()` is preferend, i.e. `for(seq_len(length(x))`. Btw `for()` + `get()` looks strange imo.